# Python error: AttributeError: Module 'scipy' has no attribute '_lib'

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, conda, anaconda3

Edit: The error has now changed to:

```
File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py:8
        from . import _iterative

ImportError: cannot import name '_iterative' from partially initialized module 'scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\ahvriend\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py)
```

I want to use the stats module from SciPy, so I installed SciPy via conda.

When I import the stats module in python ("`from scipy import stats`" or "`import scipy.stats`"), however, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: Module 'scipy' has no attribute '_lib'
```

This is the traceback

```
from scipy import stats
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py:203 in __getattr__
    return globals()[name]

KeyError: '_lib'


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[58], line 1
    from scipy import stats

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py:485
    from ._stats_py import *

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_stats_py.py:39
    from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py:105
    from ._kdtree import *

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\spatial\_kdtree.py:4
    from ._ckdtree import cKDTree, cKDTreeNode

  File _ckdtree.pyx:10 in init scipy.spatial._ckdtree

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py:283
    from . import csgraph

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\__init__.py:185
    from ._laplacian import laplacian

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_laplacian.py:7
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py:120
    from ._isolve import *

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_isolve\__init__.py:4
    from .iterative import *

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_isolve\iterative.py:150
    def bicg(A, b, x0=None, tol=1e-5, maxiter=None, M=None, callback=None, atol=None):

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_threadsafety.py:57 in decorator
    return lock.decorate(func)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_lib\_threadsafety.py:45 in decorate
    return scipy._lib.decorator.decorate(func, caller)

  File ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py:205 in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(

AttributeError: Module 'scipy' has no attribute '_lib'
```

There's a _lib folder in the scipy folder (and it's not empty), so at first glance everything seems to be in order.
I've conda installed and conda uninstalled scipy several times, but no luck so far.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: There's something wrong with your setup here. It's unlikely to be a bug in SciPy. I note that scipy seems to be installed in the base environment. It's good practice to create and activate an env before installing any packages.